# Retrieving data from dynamic URL - angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to retrieve data with the following code, where the URL of the service has a dynamic  parameter ie. the **id**, there is something wrong because the data isn't displaying, when I load the URL in the browser with this on the end:

```
../categories/165
```

could I get some help please? Thanks.

```
   ...  
    .when('/categories/:categoryId', {
        controller: 'BookCategoryController',
        templateUrl: 'views/booksincategory.html'
    })
    ...
```

**controller**

```
app.controller('BookCategoryController', ['$scope', 'bookcategories', '$routeParams',  function($scope, bookcategories, $routeParams) {
    bookcategories($scope.id).success(function(data) {
     console.log($scope.id);
    $scope.detail = data.books[$routeParams.categoryId];
    });
}]);
```

**service**

```
  app.service('bookcategories', ['$http', function($http) {
      return {
        get: function(id) {
          return $http.get('http://52.41.65.211:8028/api/v1/categories/'+ id + '/books.json')
            .success(function(data) {
              return data;
            })
            .error(function(err) {
              return err;
            });
        }
      }
    }]);
```

**booksincategory.html**

```
  <div class="category col" ng-repeat="book in detail">
     <h3 class="title">{{book.title}}</h3>
  </div>
```

Comment: you should close this thread ... u did posted new SAME question ... 
 stackoverflow.com/a/46220774/1608841

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing parameter to $scope.id from URL - angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46220672/passing-parameter-to-scope-id-from-url-angularjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your service code to :

```
 app.service('bookcategories', ['$http', function($http) {
      return {
        getAllBooks: function(id) {
          return $http.get('http://52.41.65.211:8028/api/v1/categories/'+ id + '/books.json')
         }
      }
}]);
```

and in Controller :

```
 bookcategories.getAllBooks($scope.id).then(function(response) {
    $scope.detail = response.data.books[$routeParams.categoryId];
 });
```

**EDIT2**

You have to define `$scope.id` somewhere in your controller like below :

```
$scope.id= 1 ; 
console.log($routeParams.categoryId);//check what you are getting here
bookcategories.getAllBooks($routeParams.categoryId).then(function(response) {
   $scope.detail = response.data.books[$routeParams.categoryId];
});
```

after this your service URL will go like below (Took this URL from your Question)
`http://52.41.65.211:8028/api/v1/categories/1/books.json`

See **1** in the URL its `$scope.id` !

Comment: Doesn't seem to display the data still with that, but it does remove the errors

Comment: @user1937021 please check what u are getting in response in Controller using console.log

Comment: are you sure you getting response from service ?

Comment: ah I get this ""NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://52.41.65.211:8028/api/v1/categories/undefined/books.json""

Comment: can you check value for `$scope.id` in your code. May be id value is undefined thats why above error is coming

Comment: I think it must be empty as I get nothing back when I do console.log($scope.id);

Comment: from where you are getting this value ? can you update question accordingly ?

Comment: show us the code where you are getting `$scope.id` value

Comment: I added the console.log in the original post

Comment: Before giving service call using `bookcategories.getAllBooks($scope.id)` in your controller, you must be getting value `$scope.id` before that somewhere in controller or may be hardcoded in controller like `$scope.id=1`. Can you post code from where you getting this value in controller? You are getting this value undefined.

Comment: I don't have scope.id defined anywhere could that be the problem?

Comment: I am sure that is the problem.. because see your network log; it says ` 52.41.65.211:8028/api/v1/categories/undefined/` ; you are passing `$scope.id` in `bookcategories.getAllBooks`. If id is not defined anywhere then undefined will be passed to service and will give 400 bad req error and service will fail

Comment: Where should it be defined and how? Sorry

Comment: $scope.id should be the parameter appended in the URL in the browser ie: ../categories/165

Comment: I've set this as follows: $scope.id = $routeParams.categoryId; it calls the JSON correctly but no data displayed is there something wrong my HTML?

Comment: @user1937021 `bookcategories.getAllBooks($routeParams.categoryId).then(function(response) {
   $scope.detail = response.data.books[$routeParams.categoryId];
});`

Comment: or may be just console.log $routeParams.categoryId in controller like updated answer above, just to check whether you are getting id or not?

Comment: your HTML looks fine

Answer (score 0):

`.success` & `.error` function(deprecated since angular 1.4.X) are **not chainable-friendly**, so it prevents to return a promise object from `get` method. Removing `success` & `error` callback will allow to return promise object from function. Consider using `.then` function over promise since `.success` & `.error` callback deprecated.

```
get: function(id) {
  return $http.get('http://52.41.65.211:8028/api/v1/categories/'+ id + '/books.json');
}

//controller code & pass `$routeParams.categoryId` in it
bookcategories($routeParams.categoryId).then(function(response) {
    $scope.detail = response.data.books[$routeParams.categoryId];
});
```

Comment: Can you please check this, you should use `$routeParams.categoryId` instead of `$scope.id`

Comment: Not sure, why OP overlooked this?