# Passing parameter to $scope.id from URL - angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to pass a parameter from the URL in the browser to a controller, for example, the **122** should be passed in `$scope.id` in the controller so the JSON loaded is this `http://52.41.65.211:8028/api/v1/categories/122/books.json`, not working though, any idea?

**URL example**
    http://www.example.com/categories/122

**app.js**

```
   ...  
    .when('/categories/:categoryId', {
        controller: 'BookCategoryController',
        templateUrl: 'views/booksincategory.html'
    })
    ...
```

**controller**

```
app.controller('BookCategoryController', ['$scope', 'bookcategories', '$routeParams',  function($scope, bookcategories, $routeParams) {
    bookcategories.getAllBooks($scope.id).then(function(response) {
    $scope.detail = response.data.books[$routeParams.categoryId];
  });
}]);
```

**service**

```
app.service('bookcategories', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    getAllBooks: function(id) {
      return $http.get('http://52.41.65.211:8028/api/v1/categories/'+ id + '/books.json')
     }
  }
}]);
```

**booksincategory.html**

```
  <div class="category col" ng-repeat="book in detail">
     <h3 class="title">{{book.title}}</h3>
  </div>
```

Comment: Did you get chance to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46216131/2435473)? I don't understand why you're opening multiple question.. Rather concentrate on single and fix it at one place :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your URL is `http://www.example.com/categories/122` and route params is like

```
.when('/categories/:categoryId', {
    controller: 'BookCategoryController',
    templateUrl: 'views/booksincategory.html'
})
```

then you will get the `categoryId` in the controller as `$routeParams.categoryId`

Just set `$scope.id = $routeParams.categoryId;`

just set this in your controller before calling the service. So your controller will be like

```
app.controller('BookCategoryController', ['$scope', 'bookcategories', '$routeParams',  function($scope, bookcategories, $routeParams) {
    $scope.id = $routeParams.categoryId;
    bookcategories.getAllBooks($scope.id).then(function(response) {
       $scope.detail = response.data.books;
    });
}]);
```

Just use

```
$scope.detail = response.data.books;
```

no need to use $scope.detail = response.data.books[$routeParams.categoryId]; its an incorrect syntax. Hope that will work for you. You have assigned $scope.detail incorrectly in your controller. I dint see any issue in the HTML

Comment: makes sense but nothing appears still, it seems to call the JSON correctly now, is there something wrong in my HTML?

Comment: @user1937021 use $scope.detail = response.data.books; you had used an incorrect syntax. Hope that will work for you.